# Calculate percentage free swap space with `free` and `awk`

Tags: linux, awk, ubuntu-12.04, swap

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of free swap space available.
Using something like this:

```
free | grep 'Swap' | awk '{t = $2; f = $4; print ($f/$t)}'
```

but `awk` is throwing:

```
awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
```

And I don't really understand why, my program is quite simple, is it possible I'm having a weird range error?

Comment: Works fine by using $4 and $2 directly when calculating: free | grep Swap | awk '{ print ($4/$2)}'

Comment: The `grep` is redundant as well: `free | awk '/Swap/ { print $4/$2 }'`

Answer (score 6):

Try this one :

```
free | grep 'Swap' | awk '{t = $2; f = $4; print (f/t)}'
```

In your code you are trying to print $f and $t which is respectively $FreeMemory and $TotalMemory. So i guess you have about 4gig ram in total which would refer to ~ $400000 which is a little bit over the total of fields awk uses in standard config. Apart from the easier attempt with meminfo try just printing f/t which refers to the variables and you get your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that it might be easier/more robust to read the info by using `/proc/meminfo`'s `SwapFree` line.

Something like:

```
$ grep SwapFree /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the variables. You can use plain

```
awk '{ print $4/$2 }'
```

Comment: Cool! Write-only code is the best. Can you teach me please? My awk code is too readable. I want to learn how to de-document and obfuscate it.

Comment: @Ark-kun: I tend to use variables and documentation in programs, not in one-liners. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Using the predefined variables may be fine for one-liners, but if the variables are already there (even if they're single-letter), I don't think it's good to remove them. P.S. I downvoted because this doesn't answer the question. P.P.S. Wanted to remove my downvote, because your code solves the problem (even though you haven't mentioned that), but it's locked, sorry =( The answer should have been "remove dollar signs from your local variables".

Answer (score 0):

Read it from /proc/meminfo:

```
lennart@trololol:~$ grep SwapFree /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'
0
```

Comment: I wanted the percentage of free swap!

Answer (score -2):

I realise that the question is about using "free" and "awk", but if you have SAR running, then this will give you the most recently recorded percentage value:

```
sar -S|tail -2|head -1|awk '{print $5}'
```

Comment: could you please explain in detail how this solution of yours work for better understanding of everyone

Comment: This answer has nothing whatsoever to do with the question.

Comment: sar -S gives info about swap usage. tail -2 gets last 2 lines. head -1 removes averages info. print $5 gives just the percentage value of swap. And that has got a lot to do with answering the question. Not sure why the indignant responses and downvotes. Don't worry, I won't bother wasting my time on here again.